# Subset pandas dataframe using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like :

```
>>> df
      product   desc
0        ABCD  desc1
1   ABCD1,XYZ  desc2
2      ABCD1H  desc3
3       ABCD1  desc4
4  ABCD1H,LMN  desc5
```

I want to filter out rows that have products `ABCD1` or `ABCD1 followed by any other product ID` but not `ABCD1H`. How to filter out such rows.
In the above example , I want the output as :

```
>>> df
          product   desc
    1   ABCD1,XYZ  desc2
    3       ABCD1  desc4
```

This is what I have tried so far but that does not work .

```
df2 = df.loc[df['product'].str.contains('ABCD1')]
```

It also includes `ABCD1H` in its results, i don't want that to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex "\b" is word break:

```
df[df['product'].str.contains(r'ABCD1\b')]
```

Output:

```
     product   desc
1  ABCD1,XYZ  desc2
3      ABCD1  desc4
```